# loop through json in php

Tags: php, json

i have this json i get from an api:

```
{
    "data": [{
        "BrandID": 1,
        "AccountTranID": "138483",
        "Datetime": {
            "date": "2019-07-31 21:26:15.513000",
            "timezone_type": 3,
            "timezone": "UTC"
        },
        "PartyID": 1819748,
        "UserID": "adel2X",
        "Currency": "USD",
        "ProductID": 3,
        "ProductCode": "EBZZ",
        "ProductTranID": "EBZZ-f90f07cdfeff820904c56696dd72e321",
        "GameInfoID": 698,
        "GameID": "80233",
        "GameTranID": "80238cc6c07f85144d8ade97760f2cbdbff",
        "TranType": "GAME_BET",
        "AmountReal": "-.010000000000000000",
        "AmountPlayableBonus": ".000000000000000000",
        "AmountReleasedBonus": ".000000000000000000",
        "BalanceReal": ".000000000000000000",
        "BalancePlayableBonus": ".000000000000000000",
        "BalanceReleasedBonus": ".000000000000000000",
        "RollbackTranID": null,
        "RollbackTranType": null
    }, {
        "BrandID": 1,
        "AccountTranID": "138484",
        "Datetime": {
            "date": "2019-07-31 21:26:16.037000",
            "timezone_type": 3,
            "timezone": "UTC"
        },
        "PartyID": 1819748,
        "UserID": "adel2X",
        "Currency": "USD",
        "ProductID": 3,
        "ProductCode": "GROOVY",
        "ProductTranID": "Bo-f90f07cdfeff820904c56696dd72e321re",
        "GameInfoID": 698,
        "GameID": "80233",
        "GameTranID": "80238cc6c07f85144d8ade97760f2cbdbff",
        "TranType": "GAME_WIN",
        "AmountReal": ".000000000000000000",
        "AmountPlayableBonus": ".000000000000000000",
        "AmountReleasedBonus": ".000000000000000000",
        "BalanceReal": ".000000000000000000",
        "BalancePlayableBonus": ".000000000000000000",
        "BalanceReleasedBonus": ".000000000000000000",
        "RollbackTranID": null,
        "RollbackTranType": null
    }]
}
```

i then try to loop though it using this php code:

```
$data = file_get_contents('https://example.com/example');
$json = json_decode($data);
foreach($json->data as $row) {
    foreach($row as $key => $val) {
        echo $key . ': ' . $val;
        echo '<br>';
    }}
```

I use the key 'data' in json to define the rows and then try to extract the values but no luck. I have not set the the decode value to "true" since i do not want to consider it an array, can this be the issue?
Any suggestion?

Comment: To parse json data to an array with `json_decode($json,true)`

Comment: Some values of `$row` are objects of `stdClass`. You can't just `echo` objects. Use at least `print_r`.

Comment: If you try something like `echo $row->PartyID."<br />";` with just your outer loop, you should see how to display some of the basic details and work from there.

Answer (score 1):

convert the json in associative array using [json_decode](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php). using [array_walk_recursive](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-walk-recursive.php) get all the key and value of that array.

```
//convert the json in array using json_decode
$json_array = json_decode($json, true); //true is used for 'associative array'.
//using array_walk_recursive get all the key and value
array_walk_recursive($json_array, function($item, $key){
    echo $key.':'.$item.PHP_EOL; 
});
```

[Demo](https://3v4l.org/nQLGq)

Comment: more accurate one. I forgot this function while writing my answer.+1